# List declaration with/without bracket in matlab

Tags: matlab

For example, Why are `1:5` and `[1:5]` the same in matlab? 
What is the reason behind this convention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the convention is hard to tell without asking the creators of MATLAB, but here's a little insight. I apologies if this is a bit messy.

If you don't bother reading it all, here's the executive summary:

> `:` is used to create regularly spaced vectors, while square brackets are used for concatenating.

---

First, you should know that even scalars are considered to be matrices in MATLAB. Scalars are simply 1x1 matrices, or to be more specific: 1x1x1x1x......1. There are in theory infinite amount of trailing singleton dimensions.

```
1 == [1] == [[[1]]]
```

Also:

```
a = 1;
a(1,1,1,:,:,1)    %% Messy indexing showing how you can index a matrix using more dimensions than it appears to have.

ans =
     1
```

The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) says:

> The colon operator is used to create regularly spaced vectors (and subscript arrays, and specify `for` iterations).

As scalars can be created without brackets, there's no reason you should need brackets around a clearly and unambiguously defined operator.

Brackets `[]` on the other hand creates vectors or matrices by *concatenating* values and vectors.  From the documentation:

> Square brackets are used in array construction and concatenation, and also in declaring and capturing values returned by a function.

Therefore, you can basically put brackets around anything you want. The same example as with the scalar above:

```
1:4 == [1:4] == [[[1:4]]]
```

Or around cells (doesn't change anything):

```
a = {3,1:4,'Hello, World!'}
a = 
    [3]    [1x4 double]    'Hello, World!'
b = [a]
b = 
    [3]    [1x4 double]    'Hello, World!'
```

Concatenating strings:

```
str1 = 'Hello';
str2 = ', World!';
str = [str1 str2]
str =
Hello, World!
```

Concatenating vectors:

```
[1:4, 6:8, 10]
ans =
     1     2     3     4     6     7     8    10
```

If you had to put brackets around the `1:4` part, this would be (also works, but much more cumbersome):

```
[[1:4], [6:8], 10]
ans =
     1     2     3     4     6     7     8    10
```

---

A possible reason for the convention:

**It would be inconsistent if you needed brackets around `1:3`.**

---

Unrelated: For anyone used to other programming languages, brackets inside brackets often means you "go up" one dimension. Therefore, this might be confusing to some.

Answer (score 0):

Well in a way they are and are not the same , In MATLAB every thing is a matrix , even

```
a = 5
```

is 1x1 matrix , for 1-D matrix or vector they will perform the same operation 
when you write

```
>> x=1:3

ans =

     1     2     3
```

MATLAB consider the matrix as one dimensional , like for instance in the example below it consider only the last row of the declaration

```
>> x=1:3;2:4

ans =

     2     3     4
```

but when you specify brackets it can be an nxm dimensional matrix

```
>> x=[1:3;1:3]

x =

     1     2     3
     1     2     3
```